# BMW 320D 2011 ED - Engine Malfunction Icon

Tags: engine, bmw

driving back from work and this warning light came on.. the car wet into limp mode but then was ok after 1 second. No lights on after that! today the same thing happened driving to work came on for 1 second then went off.. not sure if its a HPFP or turbo issue? anyone know?

Car: BMW 3 series 2011 Efficient Dynamics
Engine: 2.0 L diesel
Any behaviors: none car runs smoothly, tested it last night on motorway and had no warnings. Seems to happen on really cold days? and when I dont warm up car?

Comment: [*Do you haz teh codez?*](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1473/4152)

Comment: Thats the thing, the warning message doesnt stay on for me to check the code. I will try again later to force the message but the last time it happened was two days ago. It has been really cold recently? not sure if this is the issue especially if the car is a diesel?

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 see above

Comment: If the check engine light went on the code stayed in the ECU for future reading even if the light went off afterwards. Do read it.

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing the check engine light on never came on. just the warning came on the dash (little screen) with the engine malfunction warning icon [image](http://i1352.photobucket.com/albums/q641/Dan116i/BMW%20Problems/EngineManagementcopy.png)

Comment: That's called the check engine light.

Comment: Sorry, but this is check engine [light](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSgox9W2k5zUG0HR3trCWZ5K5jm2sdGSZCf9BcnCltgO-ecPtyn_g) the icon in my previous message is the engine malfunction light... I will double check the code when i finish work regardless to see!

Comment: SO I went to the mechanic he didnt tell me the code but said it was a acceleration problem but the problem is now gone? probably the cold weather!